# Issues with working with multi-index data frames

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation, multi-index

I have a huge dataframe. I'm trying to construct a multi-index dataframe here that resembles it. I need to get the number of `NaN`s based on each index and column.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'tic': ['IBM', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'IBM', 'AAPL'],
                   'industry': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                    'price': [np.nan, 5, 6, 11, np.nan],
                    'shares':[100, 60, np.nan, 100, 62],
                    'dates': pd.to_datetime(['1990-01-01', '1990-01-01','1990-04-01', 
                                                 '1990-04-01', '1990-08-01'])
                    })

temp.set_index(['tic', 'dates'], inplace=True)
```

which yields:

```
                industry  price  shares
tic  dates                             
IBM  1990-01-01        A    NaN   100.0
AAPL 1990-01-01        B    5.0    60.0
     1990-04-01        B    6.0     NaN
IBM  1990-04-01        A   11.0   100.0
AAPL 1990-08-01        B    NaN    62.0
```

Here are the issues:

1) Minor issue: Why isn't the index working? I was expecting to see one `IBM` and `AAPL` in the `tic` column.

2) How can I get ratio of `NaN`s to total data points for each `tic` on each column? So, I need a dataframe like this:

```
tic                                     IBM              AAPL 
number of total NaNs                    1                2 
percentage of NaNs in 'price' column    50%(1 out of 2)  33.3% (1 out 3)
percentage of NaNs in 'Shares' column   0% (0 out 2)     33.3% (1 out 3)
```

3) How can I rank the tics based on their ratio of `NaN`s on column `price`?

4) How can I select the top n tics with lowest ratio of `NaN`s on both columns.

5) How can I do the above between two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why isn't the index working?

```
temp.sort_index()
```

[image]

2) How can I get ratio of NaNs?

```
grpd = temp.groupby(level='tic').agg(['size', 'count'])

null_ratio = grpd.xs('count', axis=1, level=1) \
        .div(grpd.xs('size', axis=1, level=1)).mul(-1).__radd__(1)

null_ratio
```

[image]

3) rank by nulls in price column?

```
null_ratio.price.rank()

tic
AAPL    1.0
IBM     2.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

4) How can I select the top n tics with lowest ratio of NaNs on both columns?

```
null_ratio.price.nsmallest(1)

tic
AAPL    0.333333
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

5) between dates

```
temp.sort_index().loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, '1990-01-01':'1990-04-01'], :]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Regarding number 4, that is giving me nsmallest based on just column `price.` How can I get the nsmallest on BOTH `price` and `shares`? These are the two most important columns. I multiply them to get  a new column `market value.` So, I need to keep only tics that have less than n% `NaN`s on these two.

Comment: @st19297 if security A had a null ratio on price and shares of 0.1 and 0.2 respectively and security B had a null ratio of 0.09 and 0.21, how you rank them?  It sounds like you need to think about your problem a bit more.  Or use a filter.  You've gotten away with asking 5 questions in one.  If you have a new question, ask it with another post.  In fact, if you search for "How do I filter on two columns?"  I'm sure it's been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use the [sort_level](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html) function to achieve the order you desire.
   `temp.sort_level('tic', inplace=True)`
   `temp.sort_level(['tic', 'dates'], inplace=True)`
2. `df = pd.DataFrame({'total_missing': temp_grpd.apply(lambda x: x['price'].isnull().sum() + x['shares'].isnull().sum()),
                      'pnt_missing_price': temp_grpd.apply(lambda x: x['price'].isnull().sum()/x.shape[0]),
                      'pnt_missing_shares': temp_grpd.apply(lambda x: x['shares'].isnull().sum()/x.shape[0]),
                      'total_records': temp_grpd.apply(lambda x: x.shape[0])})`

If you need it, you can transpose the dataframe to match the format you included in your post, but it will likely be easier to manipulate in this format.

3. `df['pnt_missing_price'].rank(ascending=False)`
4. The problem is not well-defined. I think you probably need something like the following, but it's not clear.

   `df['pnt_missing'] = df['total_missing']/df['total_records']`
   `df.sort_values('pnt_missing', ascending=True)`
   `df.loc[df['pnt_missing'].nsmallest(5)]`
5. you already have a good answer for this one by piRSquared.